Warning: loadFont - translateFont failed: "TypeError: e.peekBytes is not a function"
I am using PDF.js (pdfjs-dist v4.7.76 (latest)) in a Angular18 project,
The pdf viewer is working well for all PDF I uploaded, except with one:
Almost all the text of the PDF is not showing :

(What I should see)

And I have this warning in the console :

Warning: loadFont - translateFont failed: "TypeError: e.peekBytes is not a function".

So I debugged the pdf.worker.min.mjs file, and I found that the error come from the getFontFileType function.
Here's the function code:
function getFontFileType(e, {type: t, subtype: i, composite: a}) {
    let s, r;
    if (function isTrueTypeFile(e) {
        const t = e.peekBytes(4);
        return 65536 === readUint32(t, 0) || "true" === bytesToString(t)
    }(e) || isTrueTypeCollectionFile(e))
        s = a ? "CIDFontType2" : "TrueType";
    else if (function isOpenTypeFile(e) {
        return "OTTO" === bytesToString(e.peekBytes(4))
    }(e))
        s = a ? "CIDFontType2" : "OpenType";
    else if (function isType1File(e) {
        const t = e.peekBytes(2);
        return 37 === t[0] && 33 === t[1] || 128 === t[0] && 1 === t[1]
    }(e))
        s = a ? "CIDFontType0" : "MMType1" === t ? "MMType1" : "Type1";
    else if (function isCFFFile(e) {
        const t = e.peekBytes(4);
        return t[0] >= 1 && t[3] >= 1 && t[3] <= 4
    }(e))
        if (a) {
            s = "CIDFontType0";
            r = "CIDFontType0C"
        } else {
            s = "MMType1" === t ? "MMType1" : "Type1";
            r = "Type1C"
        }
    else {
        warn("getFontFileType: Unable to detect correct font file Type/Subtype.");
        s = t;
        r = i
    }
    return [s, r]
}

And here's where the error come from (line 3 of the function):

The error is due to the type of the "e" variable, that should be a Stream, but is a "Dict" instead.
This is probably due to a weird font file, so I tried to open the pdf file with these options:
 pdfjs.getDocument({
   url: 'the file url',
   disableFontFace: true, // this option
   disableStream: true, // or this option
   cMapUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.6.172/cmaps/', // or these two options
   cMapPacked: true,
 });

or I added this option when I render the page :
page.render({
  canvasContext: context,
  viewport: viewport,
  renderingMode: 'svg',  // this line
})

But no one seemed to change anything. So please, did anyone already have this issue? Can you think of a way to fix it?
EDIT:
Here's the pdf file :
PDF file

According to this github issue, this kind of font types are not considered.
So I solved it by added some lines to the pdf.worker.min.mjs file, in the translateFont function:
if (E?.xref?.stream) {
  E = E.xref.stream;
}

if(u?.xref?.stream) {
  u = u.xref.stream;
}

So this way it's working perfectly fine.
My answer in my github issue: Github issue

Yup thanks it works in my viewer ! But the thing is that all the pdf files given by this company have this corrupted font, and so I need to display them all, without fixing each of them independently. But my solutions seem to work for me.
But yeah your right it would be a great idea to make PDF.js able to read every font, even if it's not following the standards..

Ok thanks I see the point now. This is such a complex subject that I get into for the first time. Thank you for these explanations!
